# Human body detection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, detection

Is there any JavaScript library for human body detection in images or video? I know [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) in C++ and Python, but I need it in JavaScript. There are also libraries for face detection, but I can't find any for the whole body.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are JavaScript ports of OpenCV that perform object detection on images or videos in real-time: [js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect) (which contains an upper body classifier) and [HAAR.js](https://github.com/foo123/HAAR.js).

More classifiers can be found in the OpenCV distribution or [on the internet](http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34), they just have to be converted into another format before they can be read by the JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the same C++ libraries integrated in a NPAPI, and then call for the C++ functions from your javascript code.

Comment: This is only useful if you want to deploy a browser plugin. (Which is a great way to drive away users.) Not so much for a webapp.